# Java script formatting Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How could I move the javascript from application_helper.rb

Currently I have javascripts in application helper

```
def js_field_formatter_phone()

 result = <<JS_DATE_FIELD_PHONE
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function js_field_formatter_phone(inputField) {
      var valueStr = inputField.value;
      var formattedStr = "";
      for (var i=0; i<valueStr.length; i++) {
          if (/^\\d/.test(valueStr.charAt(i))) {
              formattedStr += valueStr.charAt(i);
          }
      }
      inputField.value = formattedStr;
  }
 </script>
           JS_DATE_FIELD_PHONE
  return result
end
```

But this code display as raw html in my views

in my view I've

```
    <%= js_field_formatter_phone() %>

    <input type="text"
    name="billing_phone_number_home"
    size="30"
    maxlength="20"
    tabindex="<%= get_next_tabindex(@content_data) %>"
    onchange="js_field_formatter_phone(this);"
    value="<%= @content_data['billing_phone_number_home'] %>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1 uses the asset pipeline and puts javascripts in app/assets/javascripts. I'm not quite familiar with it yet, you can read about it here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

But why is this javascript in a helper at all? It doesn't appear to use the 'result' variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JavaScript in a separate file. Don't mix it in with your HTML.